# I don't find id in layout

Tags: android, listview, find

when custom list view, in method getView I use ImageView

```
img=view.findViewById();
```

I don't find Id in my layout customlistView.My code follow:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemMenu> {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    List<ItemMenu> objects;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ItemMenu> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=View.inflate(context, resource, null);
        ImageView img=view.findViewById();
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

}
```

Comment: You aren't supplying an `id` parameter, looks like.

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code

```
 ImageView img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageId);
```

Replace imageId with id of image from layout.
`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code ImageView img=view.findViewById(); with  ImageView img=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgViewId);